# spring json response onload of jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, spring-mvc

i have the below controller which produce json response

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/page", produces="application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView showPage(HttpSession session) {

    ObjectBo ObjectBo = (ObjectBo ) session.getAttribute("object");
    ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();

    if(null != ObjectBo ){
        modelMap.addAttribute("isUpdate", true);
        modelMap.addAttribute("object", ObjectBo );
        return new ModelAndView("viewpage", modelMap);
    }else {
        modelMap.addAttribute("isUpdate", false);
        modelMap.addAttribute("object", new ObjectBo());
        return new ModelAndView("viewpage", modelMap);
    }

}
```

and in JSP i am using spring form:form tag, to render my model object "`object`", everything works fine , except isUpdate attribute.

user lands on this page two ways , one from login page, and another from "back" button click on next page.

so on load of the page i need to get isUpdate value in jquery and i need to display buttons "`create`" or "`update`" based on isupdate Value, i am able to get "`object`" data.

is there a way to get json response data in jquery ready function , so that i can use the isUpdate value? without doing ajax call.

Comment: `produce json response` where are you returning json in the controller?

Comment: @Jai it will get converted to json

Comment: When I read `showPage` I rather think that you return a HTML document, not JSON. Anyway I don't understand what could possibly be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
 <script>
    var isUpdate = '<c:out value="${isUpdate}"/>';
 </script>
```

And then you can use that variable in any function.